# typescript type of response with Promise

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How can I set the type of the response variable?

```
import axios from 'axios'

function postVueX (commit: (mutation: string, data: unknown) => void,
  dispatch: (mutation: string, data: string, options?: { root: boolean }) => void,
  url: string,
  data: unknown,
  mutation: string,
  emptyResult: unknown,
  method: () => void): Promise<void> {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      return axios.post(url, data)
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response) {
        if (mutation) {
          commit(mutation, response.data)
        }
        if (method) {
          method(response.data)
        }
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      if (mutation) {
        commit(mutation, emptyResult)
      }
      dispatch('notify/error', e.response.data.message, {
        root: true
      })
    })
}
```

The linter gives me this error in catch :
Unsafe member access .response on an `any` value.

Comment: where does vm come from? Please provide a minimum reproducable example.

Answer (score 0):

"Unsafe member access .$axios on an any value." just means, that there is no proper type definition for vm, so you should either create one yourself or (prefered) get a package that already does it.

Comment: Sorry the good error is :
Unsafe member access .response on an `any` value.

Comment: that seems to be a missing type for the error you caught. My tip would be to go through all errors and fix them first. Add types where they are missing and the errors you get will be more useful.

Comment: @franfrLor your function isAxiosError has no valid return type(should be a boolean) and you didn't cast `const axiosError = e` to the type you defined

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm new to typescript
I did that what do you think?

```
export interface Erreur {
  message: string;
}

function isAxiosError (error: unknown): error is AxiosError {
  return (error as AxiosError).isAxiosError !== undefined
}

function postVueX (commit: (mutation: string, data: unknown) => void,
  dispatch: (mutation: string, data: string, options?: { root: boolean }) => void,
  url: string,
  data: unknown,
  mutation: string,
  emptyResult: unknown,
  method: (data: unknown) => void): Promise<void> {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      return axios.post(url, data)
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response) {
        if (mutation) {
          commit(mutation, response.data)
        }
        if (method) {
          method(response.data)
        }
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      let erreur = 'Erreur non trouvée'
      if (isAxiosError(e)) {
        const axiosError = e
        if (axiosError.response) {
          erreur = (<Erreur>(axiosError.response.data)).message
        }
      } else if (e instanceof Error) {
        erreur = e.message
      }
      if (mutation) {
        commit(mutation, emptyResult)
      }
      dispatch('notify/error', erreur, {
        root: true
      })
    })
}
```